# How to decode/unmarshal Request Body into Golang structs and struct slices?

Tags: go, struct

How do I properly unmarshal this in Golang?

```
{
    "symbol": "ZVZZT.O",
    "params": [{
        "forward": 0,
        "period": 3,
        "ref": "high",
        "indicator": "sma",
        "freq": "day"
    }, {
        "forward": 1,
        "period": 8,
        "ref": "close",
        "indicator": "ema",
        "freq": "week"
    }]
}
```

into these structs

```
type Iteration4RequestBody struct {
    Symbol string             `json:"symbol"`
    Params []Iteration4Params `json:"params"`
}

type Iteration4Params struct {
    Forward   int    `json:"forward"`
    Period    int    `json:"period"`
    Ref       string `json:"ref"`
    Indicator string `json:"indicator"`
    Freq      string `json:"freq"`
}
```

I need to be able to use []Iteration4Params, but right now, this is empty when I decode it

EDIT 2 (NEW CODE I USED)

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
var t Iteration4RequestBody
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &t)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(t)
```

Result is {ZVZZT.O []}

Edit 3:
Works now. Can't remember the last thing I did before it worked though. Never mind. Thanks for all your answers by the way.

Comment: Start by making your fields exported (starting with an uppercase)

Comment: Please show the code you've tried and explain the problem you're having with it.

Comment: done already in actual, haven't updated here. It only decoded the Symbol, not the slice

Comment: Works for me if I export all your fields and use `json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &instanceOfrequestBody)`

Comment: how do I get the jsonBytes from request body?

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 why are you using a `for` loop to decode the request body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm confused about a few things you're doing:

- using a for when you're decoding a `request.Body`
- expecting more than one element
- not just appending `b` directly

Dropping the loop and using either `json.Unmarshal` or `json.NewDecoder` works fine. I could keep the for loop, and it would still work. You should show the rest of your code, you have a problem elsewhere, either:

- the request body is empty or already read and closed
- you're returning the parsed objects in a strange way
- something else?

Here's working code (without the for loop), showing both possibilities:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

var j = `
{
    "symbol": "ZVZZT.O",
    "params": [{
        "forward": 0,
        "period": 3,
        "ref": "high",
        "indicator": "sma",
        "freq": "day"
    }, {
        "forward": 1,
        "period": 8,
        "ref": "close",
        "indicator": "ema",
        "freq": "week"
    }]
}`

type Iteration4RequestBody struct {
    Symbol string             `json:"symbol"`
    Params []Iteration4Params `json:"params"`
}

type Iteration4Params struct {
    Forward   int    `json:"forward"`
    Period    int    `json:"period"`
    Ref       string `json:"ref"`
    Indicator string `json:"indicator"`
    Freq      string `json:"freq"`
}

func main() {
    // Using json.Unmarshal
    var it Iteration4RequestBody
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &it)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(it)

    // Using a json.Decoder
    var it2 Iteration4RequestBody
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(j))
    if err := dec.Decode(&it2); err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(it2)
}
```

Outputs:

```
{ZVZZT.O [{0 3 high sma day} {1 8 close ema week}]}
{ZVZZT.O [{0 3 high sma day} {1 8 close ema week}]}
```

Comment: Result for me in console is { ZVZZT.O [ ] }

Comment: Please show the rest of your code, I listed a few thing that could go wrong. You should probably print the body before unmarshal too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a json.Decoder you can loop testing if there are more elements:

```
for dec.More() {
  var b Iteration4RequestBody
  if err := dec.Decode(&b); err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
  } else {
    log.Println(b)
  }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-dgg9kfjdp8